# save and load custom attention model lstm in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

I want to run a seq2seq model using lstm for a customer journey analysis.I am able to run the model but unable to load the saved model on a different notebook.

Code for attention model is here:

```
# RNN "Cell" classes in Keras perform the actual data transformations at each timestep. Therefore, in order to add attention to LSTM, we need to make a custom subclass of LSTMCell.

class AttentionLSTMCell(LSTMCell):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.attentionMode = False
    super(AttentionLSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# Build is called to initialize the variables that our cell will use. We will let other Keras
# classes (e.g. "Dense") actually initialize these variables.
@tf_utils.shape_type_conversion
def build(self, input_shape):        
    # Converts the input sequence into a sequence which can be matched up to the internal
    # hidden state.
    self.dense_constant = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.units, name="AttLstmInternal_DenseConstant"))

    # Transforms the internal hidden state into something that can be used by the attention
    # mechanism.
    self.dense_state = Dense(self.units, name="AttLstmInternal_DenseState")

    # Transforms the combined hidden state and converted input sequence into a vector of
    # probabilities for attention.
    self.dense_transform = Dense(1, name="AttLstmInternal_DenseTransform")

    # We will augment the input into LSTMCell by concatenating the context vector. Modify
    # input_shape to reflect this.
    batch, input_dim = input_shape[0]
    batch, timesteps, context_size = input_shape[-1]
    lstm_input = (batch, input_dim + context_size)

    # The LSTMCell superclass expects no constant input, so strip that out.
    return super(AttentionLSTMCell, self).build(lstm_input)

# This must be called before call(). The "input sequence" is the output from the 
# encoder. This function will do some pre-processing on that sequence which will
# then be used in subsequent calls.
def setInputSequence(self, input_seq):
    self.input_seq = input_seq
    self.input_seq_shaped = self.dense_constant(input_seq)
    self.timesteps = tf.shape(self.input_seq)[-2]

# This is a utility method to adjust the output of this cell. When attention mode is
# turned on, the cell outputs attention probability vectors across the input sequence.
def setAttentionMode(self, mode_on=False):
    self.attentionMode = mode_on

# This method sets up the computational graph for the cell. It implements the actual logic
# that the model follows.
def call(self, inputs, states, constants):
    # Separate the state list into the two discrete state vectors.
    # ytm is the "memory state", stm is the "carry state".
    ytm, stm = states
    # We will use the "carry state" to guide the attention mechanism. Repeat it across all
    # input timesteps to perform some calculations on it.
    stm_repeated = K.repeat(self.dense_state(stm), self.timesteps)
    # Now apply our "dense_transform" operation on the sum of our transformed "carry state" 
    # and all encoder states. This will squash the resultant sum down to a vector of size
    # [batch,timesteps,1]
    # Note: Most sources I encounter use tanh for the activation here. I have found with this dataset
    # and this model, relu seems to perform better. It makes the attention mechanism far more crisp
    # and produces better translation performance, especially with respect to proper sentence termination.
    combined_stm_input = self.dense_transform(
        keras.activations.relu(stm_repeated + self.input_seq_shaped))
    # Performing a softmax generates a log probability for each encoder output to receive attention.
    score_vector = keras.activations.softmax(combined_stm_input, 1)
    # In this implementation, we grant "partial attention" to each encoder output based on 
    # it's log probability accumulated above. Other options would be to only give attention
    # to the highest probability encoder output or some similar set.
    context_vector = K.sum(score_vector * self.input_seq, 1)

    # Finally, mutate the input vector. It will now contain the traditional inputs (like the seq2seq
    # we trained above) in addition to the attention context vector we calculated earlier in this method.
    inputs = K.concatenate([inputs, context_vector])

    # Call into the super-class to invoke the LSTM math.
    res = super(AttentionLSTMCell, self).call(inputs=inputs, states=states)

    # This if statement switches the return value of this method if "attentionMode" is turned on.
    if(self.attentionMode):
        return (K.reshape(score_vector, (-1, self.timesteps)), res[1])
    else:
        return res
# Custom implementation of the Keras LSTM that adds an attention mechanism.


# This is implemented by taking an additional input (using the "constants" of the RNN class into the LSTM: The encoder output vectors across the entire input sequence.

class LSTMWithAttention(RNN):
def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    cell = AttentionLSTMCell(units=units)
    self.units = units
    super(LSTMWithAttention, self).__init__(cell, **kwargs)

@tf_utils.shape_type_conversion
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.input_dim = input_shape[0][-1]
    self.timesteps = input_shape[0][-2]
    return super(LSTMWithAttention, self).build(input_shape) 

# This call is invoked with the entire time sequence. The RNN sub-class is responsible
# for breaking this up into calls into the cell for each step.
# The "constants" variable is the key to our implementation. It was specifically added
# to Keras to accomodate the "attention" mechanism we are implementing.
def call(self, x, constants, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        self.x_initial = x[0]
    else:
        self.x_initial = x

    # The only difference in the LSTM computational graph really comes from the custom
    # LSTM Cell that we utilize.
    self.cell._dropout_mask = None
    self.cell._recurrent_dropout_mask = None
    self.cell.setInputSequence(constants[0])
    return super(LSTMWithAttention, self).call(inputs=x, constants=constants, **kwargs)
```

Code defining encoder and decoder model:

```
# Encoder Layers
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,len_input), name="attenc_inputs")
encoder = LSTM(units=units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder((encoder_inputs))
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

#define inference decoder
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
#encoder_model.save('atten_enc_model.h5')

# define training decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_output))
Attention_dec_lstm = LSTMWithAttention(units=units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
# Note that the only real difference here is that we are feeding attenc_outputs to the decoder now.

attdec_lstm_out, _, _ = Attention_dec_lstm(inputs=decoder_inputs, 
                                    constants=encoder_outputs, 
                                    initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense1 = Dense(units, activation="relu")
decoder_dense2 = Dense(n_output, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense2(Dropout(rate=.10)(decoder_dense1(Dropout(rate=.10)(attdec_lstm_out))))

atten_model =  Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
atten_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
atten_model.summary()

#Defining inference decoder

state_input_h = Input(shape=(units,), name="state_input_h")
state_input_c = Input(shape=(units,), name="state_input_c")
decoder_states_inputs = [state_input_h, state_input_c]
attenc_seq_out = Input(shape=encoder_outputs.get_shape()[1:], name="attenc_seq_out")
attenc_seq_out
inf_attdec_inputs = Input(shape=(None,n_output), name="inf_attdec_inputs")
attdec_res, attdec_h, attdec_c = Attention_dec_lstm(inputs=inf_attdec_inputs, 
                                    constants=attenc_seq_out, 
                                    initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [attdec_h, attdec_c]

decoder_model = Model(inputs=[inf_attdec_inputs, state_input_h, state_input_c, attenc_seq_out], 
                             outputs=[attdec_res, attdec_h, attdec_c])
```

Code for model fit and save:

```
history = atten_model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size_num,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2,verbose=1)
atten_model.save('atten_model_lstm.h5')
```

Code to load the encoder decoder model with custom Attention layer:

```
with open('atten_model_lstm.json') as mdl:
    json_string = mdl.read()
    model = model_from_json(json_string, custom_objects={'AttentionLSTMCell': AttentionLSTMCell, 'LSTMWithAttention': LSTMWithAttention})
```

This code to load is giving error :

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AttentionLSTMCell'
```

Comment: Here's a good resource on how to save/load models in keras https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/. Unfortunately I'm typing on my phone right now, so I can't provide a "nicer" answer with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution inspired by the [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/) in my comment:

```
# serialize model to JSON
atten_model_json = atten_model.to_json()
with open("atten_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(atten_model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
atten_model.save_weights("atten_model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# Different part of your code or different file
# load json and create model
json_file = open('atten_model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("atten_model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```